# proving $\left\lVert Z \right\rVert_{2} \leq \left\lVert Z \right\rVert_{1}^{\frac{1}{4}} \left\lVert Z \right\rVert_{3}^{\frac{3}{4}}$

Tags: probability, inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, holder-inequality

I'm trying to prove Khintchine’s inequality and the book suggested using this inequality to prove it. I'm assuming I should use Hölder's inequality but I can't seem to reach the correct result. My attempt is:

$\left\lVert z \right\rVert_{2} = \left( E|z|^2 \right)^{1/2}$

$E|z|^2 = E|z^{p} z^{q}|$

I assume I should factorize the power of 2 to some p and q such that when I use Hölder's inequality it works, but I can't seem to find the right combination.

Comment: Try $|Z|^2=|Z|^{1/2}|Z|^{3/2}$, and apply Cauchy-Schwarz (which is of course a special case of Holder).

Comment: I tried it but it ended up with $ E|z^{1/2}| <= (E|z|)^{1/2} (E|z|^3)^{1/2}$. which still doesn't satisfy the inequality.

Comment: It does. You just need to remember how the $L^p$ norms are defined. You have an extra square root from the beginning, so that’s where the $\frac{1}{4}$ comes from. Then you have $E(|Z|^3)$ which gives $\|Z\|_3^3$. Also, typo on the LHS it should be $E(|z|^2)$ not $E|z^{1/2}|$.

Comment: You're right, now it works, I totally forgot the extra 1/2. Thank you !